# File execution error - No module named 'pywinauto'

Tags: python, cmd, spyder, pywinauto

I am trying to run the `.exe` file that I have created from my `.py` file using pyinstaller. The script was written in Spyder (Python 3.8). The python version on my computer is 3.8 as well. The pyisntaller command runs without any errors and creates `.exe` file in the `dist` folder. However, when I try to run the generated `.exe` file, nothing hapens (apart from the black screen coming up with some "light speed" dispayed error).

I have decided to run it in CMD, so I can see what error is being produced...here is the message I get upon execution of `.exe` file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "myScript.py", line 8, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pywinauto'
[13024] Failed to execute script myScript
```

The important thing to note, is that, while running the script directly from Spyder, it runs without any error.

I have tried installing pywinauto, using pip, but the error still persists.
Any idea would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Copy the following code as the first line of all your Python sources:

```
 print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2:<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
```

You have to make sure that for your main.py file:

```
__name__ is __main__ and __package__ must be None
```

You have to make sure that for your packages files:

```
__name__ is the name of the file and __package__ must be the name of the package
```

I fixed this issue reading this (Solution 1):

https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent